# AlexNet implementation with different number of classes

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I'm trying to test a dataset with AlexNet. I'm using [this](https://engmrk.com/alexnet-implementation-using-keras/) implementation.
The problem is that my dataset has 11 classes, but the code on that site uses as output layer 1000 classes. Do I just need to change the last part:

```
# 3rd Fully Connected Layer
model.add(Dense(1000))
model.add(Activation(‘relu’))
# Add Dropout
model.add(Dropout(0.4))

# Output Layer
model.add(Dense(17))
model.add(Activation(‘softmax’))
```

To:

```
# 3rd Fully Connected Layer
model.add(Dense(11))
model.add(Activation(‘relu’))
# Add Dropout
model.add(Dropout(0.4))

# Output Layer
model.add(Dense(17))
model.add(Activation(‘softmax’))
```

So that I can test my dataset?

PS I'm new to machine learning in general, sorry if this is a stupid question

Comment: If you find my answer useful, consider upvote it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your dataset has 11 classes, change the number of output in the last layer to 11. Try this:

```
# 3rd Fully Connected Layer
# This is only the output of a hidden layer, you don't have to change this
model.add(Dense(1000)) 
model.add(Activation(‘relu’))
# Add Dropout
model.add(Dropout(0.4))

# Output Layer
# This is what you want to change
model.add(Dense(11))
model.add(Activation(‘softmax’))
```